# Pointwise upper bound on a harmonic function away from boundary

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, elliptic-operators

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain and let $u$ be a harmonic function on $\Omega$ such that the gradient of $u$ squared integrates to $1$. How can we obtain pointwise upper bounds on $u(x)$ depending only on the distance of the point $x$ from the boundary of $\Omega$?

I obtained this problem from Michael Dafermos' page on Princeton Generals (see [here](http://web.math.princeton.edu/generals/dafermos_michael), second question under *Analysis*). I find this question really interesting and highly appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: Er, we could add any constant we like to $u$, that doesn't change the gradient.

Comment: If the gradient integrates to $1$ on the boundary then (from the Poisson kernel) you can obtain a bound for $\nabla f(x)$ in term of $\min_{y \in \partial \Omega} |x-y|$

Comment: Thank you for posting the link to Princeton Generals. I agree that the question is interesting. The interpretation of reuns is probably the right one.